# Choose Correct Reverse Proxy Via URL Parameter

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, git

From my understanding of git, the http/https interface is simple. You have two commands - push and fetch.

Based on a wireshark trace the fetch URL appears to be in this format:

```
/git/#path-to-repo#/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

The push URLs appear to be in these formats:

```
/git/#path-to-repo#/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
/git/#path-to-repo#/git-receive-pack
```

I would like to setup nginx configuration so that pushes go to one git backend and fetches come from a different one (the git mirror using gitblit federation).

So I set up a nginx configuration like this:

```
proxy_cache_bypass $arg_preview;

location ~ (.*)git-receive-pack {
     proxy_pass http://#push-ip#:8080;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 80;
}

location / {
     proxy_pass http://#pull-ip#:8080/;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 80;
}
```

Whilst this configuration correctly sends /git/#path-to-repo#/git-receive-pack format URLs to the push IP, the /git/#path-to-repo#/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack format URLs still go to the pull IP.

How can I get URLs of the form /git/#path-to-repo#/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack to go to the #push-ip# as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this was easier than I thought. Just added another section between the first and second location block:

```
location ~ (.*)\/refs {
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 80;
     if ($arg_service = "git-receive-pack") {
         proxy_pass http://#push-ip#:8080;
         break;
     }
     proxy_pass http://#pull-ip#:8080;
}
```